# Do Postgres temporary tables exist between multiple connections open at once?

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

Say I open a new `npgsqlconnection` and create a new temporary table `temp1`, and then open another new connection. From my understanding a temporary table is only available to the session that opened it, and two open connections shouldn't share the same session. Here the connection strings are identical, and I tried turning pooling off, but that didn't change anything. The pseudo-code is:

```
var conn1 = new NpgsqlConnection(MyConnectionString)
var conn2 = new NpgsqlConnection(MyConnectionString)
conn1.Open()
conn2.Open()
conn1.Execute("CREATE TEMP TABLE temp1(idx int)")
```

If I execute the query `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pg_tables WHERE tablename = 'temp1'` for both connections this query returns 1. Why would `conn2` be able to access the temporary table created on `conn1`? Is there anyway to prevent this?

Comment: The connection string indicates which database and user is connecting. Just because the connection string is identical does NOT indicate it's the same session.  If it were you could only fave 1 user at a given time on the application. In your pseudo-code conn1 and conn2 could each create the temp table, but they are not the the same, each unique to its own session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why would conn2 be able to access the temporary table created on conn1?

It can't.

The other connections can see that there is a table via the system catalog, but they cannot access it.

```
-- Connection 1
test=# SELECT schemaname FROM pg_tables WHERE tablename = 'temp1';
 schemaname 
------------
 pg_temp_3
(1 row)

-- Connection 2
test=# select * from pg_temp_3.temp1;
ERROR:  cannot access temporary tables of other sessions
```